# how to do postback on changing dropdownlist selected item in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown in my page. On selecting a value in dropdown I want the label text to be changed. Here is my code :

```
@model FND.Models.ViewLender

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Lender";
 }

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("Change Lender : ")
    @Html.DropDownList("Ddl_Lender", Model.ShowLenderTypes)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
 }
```

On changing the value in dropdownlist I want the Description to change accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could start by putting the description into a div and give your dropdown an unique id:

```
@model FND.Models.ViewLender

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Lender";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("Change Lender : ")
    @Html.DropDownList("Ddl_Lender", Model.ShowLenderTypes, new { id = "lenderType" })
    <div id="description">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
}
```

Now all that's left is to subscribe to the `onchange` javascript event of this dropdown and update the corresponding description.

For example if you are using jQuery that's pretty trivial task:

```
$(function() {
    $('#lenderType').change(function() {
        var selectedDescription = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#description').html(selectedDescription);
    });
});
```

---

This being said I probably misunderstood your question and this description must come from the server. In this case you could use AJAX to query a controller action that will return the corresponding description. All we need to do is provide the url to this action as an HTML5 data-* attribute to the dropdown to avoid hardcoding it in our javascript file:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Ddl_Lender", 
    Model.ShowLenderTypes, 
    new { 
        id = "lenderType", 
        data_url = Url.Action("GetDescription", "SomeController") 
    }
)
```

and now in the `.change` event we trigger the AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#lenderType').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { value: selectedValue },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#description').html(result.description);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and the last step of course is to have this controller action that will fetch the corresponding description based on the selected value:

```
public ActionResult GetDescription(string value)
{
    // The value variable that will be passed here will represent
    // the selected value of the dropdown list. So we must go ahead 
    // and retrieve the corresponding description here from wherever
    // this information is stored (a database or something)
    string description = GoGetTheDescription(value);

    return Json(new { description = description }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time <3